# Python Matplotlib How to create subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, astronomy

I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding how to create good subplots. I want to create a figure that is similar to the one shown below. Does anyone know how I could set up a similar template as this?

[image]

Also, how would I include these points with error bars in the subplots?
This is my code for the error bars:

```
mass, p, errp, errl = np.loadtxt('/Users/shawn/Desktop/vika1.dat', usecols = [0, 10, 11, 12], unpack = True)

plt.errorbar(mass, np.log10(p) - 4, yerr = [np.log10(p) - np.log10(p-errl), np.log10(p + errp) - np.log10(p)], fmt = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'w', markeredgecolor = 'k', ecolor = 'k')
```

Comment: I believe the linked duplicate and its answers (not just the accepted one) are the main part of the question: removing the gaps. Also, I suggest using `sharex` and `sharey` for these plots, if applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sharex and sharey to share the axes.  The following will give the layout you want.  You can then plot individual subplots using your specific plot funcitons.

Updated complete code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes  = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
C, S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

axes[0,0].plot(X, C, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
axes[0,1].plot(X, C, color="orange", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
axes[1,0].plot(X, C, color="green", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
axes[1,1].plot(X, C, color="red", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Can't understand why someone has downvoted me for the initial answer...

The below lines would prune the min value for both x and y axes thereby avoiding label overlaps

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
axes[1,1].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
axes[1,1].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
```

Comment: Hm.... seems to work well. However, is there a way to prevent the numbers on the axes from overlapping?